# Django render with context to VueJS

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, vue.js

I have a django view, that renders a template with context that includes data based on a form input. Now I want to access that context data.

View function:

```
def view_function(request):
    ...
    ...
    context = {
       'dataList': datalist
    }
return render(request, 'template.html', context = context)
```

Template:

```
var app = new Vue({
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            search: "",
            dataList: [],
        },
        created(){
            this.dataList = ...
        }
})
```

Is there a way to get the context from Django into VueJS `dataList`?

Comment: What about rendering a `JsonResponse` in your Django view? That should be easier to consume with a JavaScript client.

Comment: Other option would be to introspect the DOM and parse the context.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best option to combine django with vue is to create api using, for example, the django-rest-framework.

In vue js we use axios to communicate with our api and the best option for keeping the data will be vuex

Helpful links
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/
https://medium.com/quick-code/crud-app-using-vue-js-and-django-516edf4e4217

Comment: Thank you. I have always done that, with either "fetch..." or axios. I was however trying to apply vue to an existing template and framework.
Thank you anyway for your help!